# Cannot Execute FTP commands using ftp.exe client on AWS EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: ftp, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use ftp.exe from powershell for ftp connection. I can login to ftp server  through credential but when I run any command it through 
"500 Illegal PORT command.
425 Use PORT or PASV first."

Server is on ubuntu and client is on windows ec2.

I think It's a problem of active and passive mode in ftp.
But I dont know how to solve this, need help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ports forwarded to your machine, than try executing PASV before any other command. Seems like the FTP server you're trying to connect to block the range for its data ports.

Comment: right now from both end, I have open all ports.may be its a issue of internal and external IP,because this problem happened with only ec2,from my machine I can send files.

Comment: Can you see if the ec2 server is listening on the outside IP? netstat -anb and look for the FTP Server and the LISTENING lines.

Comment: "netstat -a | grep ftp" and result is "tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN".   this is one ubuntu server.

Comment: Can you probe that port? I usually use Port Ping (pping.exe ip port). See if it has any result, my guess is you'll see a timeout.

Comment: Both end pping.exe shows 21 is open and 20 is closed.

Comment: FTP data transfers are not 21/20. They are usually 1024+ and the ftp server opens them only when a transfer is made. Just use netcat or something to listen to one of those ports, and try to connect to it

Comment: nc -z -v -n IP "portrange" and it gave me"failed connection refused"

Comment: try `nc -l -vv -p 1025` and then probe that port (1025). If it's still refused it's a firewall (weirdly trying to be transparent i guess),

Comment: Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 1025)

Comment: Try to pping to this port now. (can't move this discussion to chat)

Comment: "closed",when I pping that port. I have tried another ftp client and works fine. but I want ftp.exe to work.:(

Comment: It's because the port is closed by some firewall, just try PASV in ftp.exe before using any other command and it should work.

Comment: tried "quote pasv" it enters in the passive mode but then when I run "get" command it gives "425 Failed to establish connection"

Comment: Windows' command line FTP client seems to not really support passive connections, try `ncftp` or `passive-ftp`